# Adding accessibilityIdentifier to UITabBarButton

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I'm displaying a `UITabBar` in my app, and am trying to assign `accessibilityIdentifier`s to the buttons. To accomplish this, I use the following lines in each of my view controller instantiations:

```
viewController.tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier = @"ViewControllerID";
```

These viewControllers all get added to the `UITabBar` like so:

```
NSMutableArray *tabBarItems = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i=0; i<_viewControllers.count; i++) {
    UIViewController *viewController = [_viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];
    [viewController setCommonTabBarController:self];
    [self addChildViewController:viewController];

    if (i == 0) {
        viewController.view.frame = self.currentTabView.bounds;
        [self.currentTabView addSubview:viewController.view];
        [self addConstraintsToSubView:viewController.view];
        _selectedViewController = viewController;
        _selectedIndex = 0;
    }

    [viewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [tabBarItems addObject:[viewController tabBarItem]];
}

[self.tabBar setItems:tabBarItems animated:animated];
```

So, what I think should be happening here, is we are grabbing the `tabBarItem` that has the `accessibilityIdentifier` set correctly (when I set breakpoints, the `accessibilityIdentifier` of each view controller is what I expect.) Then, when it is actually displayed, there is no `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Things I've noticed:

iOS is using `UITabBarButton` instead of `UITabBarItem`. I think that has something to do with it. When I print out the `items` array of the tab bar, each of the items has the correct `accessibilityIdentifier`, however, none of the `UITabBarButton` objects has the `accessibilityIdentifier` of the associated tab bar item.

Does anyone know why the accessibility identifier isn't, for lack of a better word, "carrying through" to the `UITabBarButton` object that iOS uses?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour, I guess this is worth filing a radar to apple.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? I'm implementing UITests, and trying to get the correct tabBarItem without relying on the title in the button (localization)..

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem trying to add accessibility identifiers to UITabbar items for UITesting, I was able to do it using this workaround which is not perfectly sane but it works:

```
[self.tabBar setItems:tabBarItems animated:animated];

NSArray *identifiers = @[@"itemIdentifier1", @"itemIdentifier2", @"itemIdentifier3"];
int index = 0;

for (UIControl *control in controller.tabBar.subviews)
{
    if ([control isKindOfClass:UIControl.class] && index < identifiers.count)
    {
        //This is actually the UITabBarButton
        control.accessibilityIdentifier = identifiers[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

The key is to assign the identifiers to the UITabbar subviews after the tabs have been added, which means the UITabBarButton objects have been created and ready to have an identifier set.